# How to set HTTP header on Joomla's JSON response?

Tags: joomla-3.x, json

I am using Joomla\CMS\Response\JsonResponse to send a JSON response.

```
$data= new \stdClass()
$data->some_data = 1;
$resp = new JsonResponse($data);
echo $resp;
```

How to set a HTTP header for the response?

Comment: I am noticing that you are using `return` instead of `echo` in your snippet, so I am wondering how you are using this technique.  You will see in the documentation https://docs.joomla.org/JSON_Responses_with_JResponseJson that this class does more than just `json_encode()` data.  Either way, you don't necessarily need to go to the trouble to declare an object because an array will do just fine. E.g. `return new JsonResponse(['some_data' => 1]);` Can you show us more of what you are trying to do?  Adding context is a great way to add clarity to a question.

Comment: I used the static method JResponse::setHeader(...) and it worked (but is deprecated)

Comment: Please edit your question so that the full story is in the question body.  Thank you.

Comment: could you please edit your question to show the code that you were using to create the json data and set the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended replacement according to the Joomla documentation:

> ```
> Element                   Line        Description
> \JResponse::setHeader()   83          3.2 Use JApplicationWeb::setHeader() instead
> ```

https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/deprecated.html